# Server Request or HTTP(Browser) Request

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, httprequest

How am I find out the request whether its from server (SERVER REQUEST) or browser (HTTP REQUEST) using PHP. When a file called from another file (using eg:SOAP ,CURL,..) or run a file directly from browser.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “server request” in HTTP. Even if it is a “web server” _making_ a request, he is _acting_ as the client in this scenario.

Comment: have you tried looking at the user agent? I'm not sure about soap, and it does depend on whether the CURL request has a useragent header set, also don't forget that CURL can set its useragent to appear as a browser anyway. Most browsers can also override their useragent either in settings or in a plugin. perhaps you could expand the question with some reason for needing to know?